# buffer.js:246 "Object 1 has no method 'toLowerCase'

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I m trying to make a .smil (.xml) parser in javascript.
But when I want to test it, node.js just say me that:

```
buffer.js:246
    switch(encoding && encoding.toLowerCase()){
                                ^
TypeError: Object 1 has no method 'toLowerCase'
    at Function.Buffer.isEncoding (buffer.js:246:32)
    at assertEncoding (fs.js:98:27)
    at Object.fsread (fs.js:422:5)
    at gets (/home/pi/SMIL_Parser.js:8:8)
    at read_until (/home/pi/SMIL_Parser.js:28:14)
    at home/pi/SMIL_Parser.js:64:14
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:93.15)
```

gets () is indeed one of my function:

```
var io=require('fs');
...
function gets (file){
    var chaine="", cache="", pkmn=0;
    io.read(file, cache, 0, 1, null, function(err, byte, buf){
        if (err || byte===0){return -1;}
        while ((cache!=="\n"))
        {
            chaine=chaine+cache;
            cache="";
            pkmn=io.readSync(file, cache, 0, 1, null);
            if (pkmn===0){return -1;}
        }
    });
}
```

I just don t have any idea of what go wrong, it seem to be read, but I ve made sure to get the right arguments, tried to update node.js, fs and npm. And the only similar error I found on google was a update problem.

EDIT:
Added the complete error message, here function read_until:

```
function read_until(smil, limit){
    var line="";
    do
    {
        line=gets(smil);
        if (line===-1){return -1}
    }while (!(line.search(limit)));
    return 0;
}
```

.

```
function parse (pathname){
    var smil=0, line="", pkmn=0;
    io.open(pathname, 'r', function (err, fd){
        if (err){return -1;}
        smil=fd;
        pkmn=read_until(smil, "<smil>");
        ...
```

Comment: It would appear that type of "encoding" is not a string.

Comment: Sure, but is there any way to get message from read or other libraries function? So I could know wich var isn t properly initialized?

Comment: You should be able to see in your stack trace, which line is producing the call.  If we know which line in your 'gets' function is resulting in the call to Function.Buffer.isEncoding, we could help more.  Or rather, a line like this: Object.fsread (fs.js:422:5).  Except, instead of fs.js:422:5 we want the first line that matches the name of a file you've developed, it should match the file that contains your "gets" function.

Comment: Where is the rest of the stack trace?

Comment: Edited to add the rest of the stack trace and the other custom function named in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fs.read` [takes a buffer not a string.](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_read_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback)

Change your cache to be a buffer.

```
function gets (file){
    var chaine="", cache=new Buffer(), pkmn=0;
    io.read(file, cache, 0, 1, null, function(err, byte, buf){
        if (err || byte===0){return -1;}
        while ((cache!=="\n"))
        {
            chaine=chaine+cache;
            cache="";
            pkmn=io.readSync(file, cache, 0, 1, null);
            if (pkmn===0){return -1;}
        }
    });
}
```

See the [fs.read code here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L411)

If you want to use a string as a "buffer" then you must use the legacy interface

**legacy string interface** `fs.read(fd, length, position, encoding, callback)`

Comment: Good point because I didn t saw that, but now I m getting an error at new Buffer: "First argument needs to be a number, array or string"

Comment: Ya, you need to initialize a size of the buffer. I should be the same as the `length` value, so in this case 1. `new Buffer(1)`

Comment: Ok, You just need to have a size for the buffer, since I only read 1byte I put new Buffer(1). I still have some error, but there not related to this. Thanks you all!

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the part of your code that defines `encoding` I can't tell you precisely what is wrong, but `encoding` is clearly not a string.  `.toLowerCase()` is a method of the String object.